# Cannot get crystal reports 8.5 reports to run under Windows 8 for a VB6 project

Tags: sql-server, windows-8, vb6, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a rather large code base in visual basic 6. The database server is sql server 2000. For reports we are using Crystal Reports 8.5. I have been successful in installing the prerequisites including the visual basic runtime + sp6 components and everything else on windows 8 after a lot of googling. The only difference with installation of visual basic components on windows 8 in the fact that I had to uncheck installation of Data Access->Ado, RDS and Ole Db Providers. Now my crystal reports are not opening from inside my program AND the crystal reports 8.5 report designer. The error I get is "Unable to open SQL Server ". Does anyone have a solution? How do I install the ADO, RDS and OLEDB Providers manually?

Comment: Are you asking about installing the actual Data Access pieces (read: MDAC/WDAC?), or are you asking about all of the DLL's that Crystal uses to talk to the data source (p2*.dll) that live in %WINDIR%\Crystal?

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Installing the OLE DB Provider for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198252%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) 
and the middle of this [page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15748), where the ASOLEDB9.msi packages are (32 and 64 bit versions). Those packages will install the sqloledb provider.